# Django deserialize - I've specified a natural key manager but it wont' deserialize

Tags: django, serialization

First off, this is the page I used as a guide to put this together: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/

Here is my model definition:

```
class LocationManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, zip_code):
        return self.get(zip_code=zip_code)

class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField('City', blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField('State', blank=True, null=True, max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    zip_code = models.CharField('Zip Code', blank=False, null=False, max_length=9, unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateField('Date Added')

    objects = LocationManager()

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.zip_code
```

Here's a serialized item I'm trying to deserialize:

```
    {
        "pk": 10259, 
        "model": "news.news", 
        "fields": {
            "content": "some content", 
            "created_on": "2012-07-24T16:10:44.570", 
            "location": "99801", 
            "title": "Some title"
        }
    }
```

The code I'm trying to deserialize the json with:

```
    for news_obj in serializers.deserialize('json', news_json):
        news_obj.save()
```

The error I get is:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "news" violates foreign key constraint "news_location_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (location_id)=(99801) is not present in table "location".
```

So it seems it is trying to resolve the zip_code as the natural key rather than trying to check if the item exists in the database using the natural key I defined.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that worked for me.  It appears that the natural key expects a list instead of a single field, guessing they only planned natural key to be a combination of fields' values.  I resolved this by return the zip_code in a list.

```
def natural_key(self):
    return [self.zip_code]
```

After doing this, the deserialization worked just as I wanted it to.

The resulted encoded JSON after doing this looked like this:

```
{
    "pk": 10661, 
    "model": "news.news", 
    "fields": {
        "content": "", 
        "created_on": "2012-07-25T10:19:56.627", 
        "location": [
            "36101"
        ], 
        "article_date": "2012-07-25T10:05:56", 
        "title": ""
    }
}
```